# Return input value in parent element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

```
<tr role="row" class="odd parent">
    <td class="quantity"><input type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="child">
    <td class="child" colspan="8">
        <li data-dtr-offset-index-"7">
            <span class="dtr-title"></span>
            <span class="dtr-data">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button>
            </span>
        </li>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The parent row has an input for quantity. The child row has a button. I want to click the button and return the quantity. So far I've tried:

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function(e) {

    var qty = $(this).closest("input").val();

});
```

But this returns undefined.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: where is `input` tag in your html?

Comment: sorry, i made an edit and didn't space the sample code properly. just updated it! @DmitriyLoskutov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The parent row has an input for quantity. The child row has a button.

Note, the first `tr` is not a parent of second `tr`; the `tr` elements are siblings within `html` at Question.

Try adjusting selector at `.closest()` to `tr` , chain `.prev()` with selector `tr` , `.find()` with selector `input` , `.val()`

```
$(this).closest("tr").prev("tr").find("input").val()
```